# How to run content scripts in iframes without an src

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to create a userscript that runs everywhere on `document_start`, including sub-documents. I have mostly succeeded by adding `all_frames: true` to the manifest. However there are still some places where the script isn't run, namely iframes without an `src`.

For example iframes with an srcdoc:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>"></iframe>
```

Or when they are created dynamically:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.textContent = 'Test';
```

How can I make sure that the script also runs in these subdocuments?

Do I have to add event listeners or overwrite `document.createElement` in the parent document to manually insert the script every time an iframe is created?
Or is there a better way?

Comment: Declare your content script with `"match_about_blank": true`

Comment: Are you making a Chrome extension, or a Tampermonkey script?

Comment: This is a Chrome extension with a content script. Is match_about_blank available for content scripts? I didn't see it mentioned in the specs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410165/331508.  Not sure it still works in Chrome (works in FF), test it and see.

Comment: @J.Doe, the docs were rewritten recently, and they obviously forgot to mention it, I'll notify the devs.

Comment: The info has been restored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain that what is the use of "match\_about\_blank" in chrome extension's manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408936/can-anyone-explain-that-what-is-the-use-of-match-about-blank-in-chrome-extensi)